# DateTime::createFromFormat is this a bug?

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I would like to parse a date with this kind of format "26 January | 03h" but it does not work with `\DateTime::createFromFormat`. Is this a bug ? Or am I doing something wrong !?

```
<?php
$format = 'j F | H\h';
$nowStr =  (new \DateTime())->format($format);
$newDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $nowStr);
if ($newDate === false){
    echo "What the F***!?";
}
else{
    echo "My mistake!";
}
```

[Test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2aa03594c6993b6e437dd3685b2f676da32576d2) it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a bug. The pipe (`|`) character is a valid character format for Date, so you need to escape it:

> |     Resets all fields (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, fraction and timzone information) to the Unix Epoch if they have not been parsed yet

E.g.:

```
$format = 'j F \| H\h';
```

Test it [here](https://repl.it/FVfn/0). :)

Comment: Okay, I could have found that -_-...Thanks!